# Flood Fill Image in React Native (Paint Bucket Tool, Coloring an Image)

Tags: react-native, paint, npm-install, flood-fill

Is there a library or something for react native that can manipulate images? I am searching for something which I can use for a flood fill on image in react native.

I want to make a coloring application like those ones and I want to have a paint bucket tool and a brush for now.

[A coloring application 1](https://thumbs.mic.com/MjQ0NWJhY2FhOSMvVU5xLUZJMm5IYzBtVldYWHptdHkzWFhhNTlNPS9maXQtaW4vNzYweDAvZmlsdGVyczpub191cHNjYWxlKCk6cXVhbGl0eSg4MCk6bm9fdXBzY2FsZSgpOmZvcm1hdChqcGVnKS9odHRwOi8vaW1hZ2VzLm1pYy5jb20vZ2ZzOGN1aXBrcGFra3NoeGVhMWVlZ2l2YjZmYnNuZ2hleXZxb3Y1Yzd3YWVkc25vNjBxcnB4dXc5N3Vnd2Fkci5naWY.gif)

Any idea for a library/module that I can use for a brush and a paint bucket tool(flood fill) on an image? Documentation and tutorials would be amazing.

Comment: Have you managed to procedd with SVG? Is it the good path? I also want to create a coloring feature in my app. :)